# Microsoft appcenter service url for Azure Dev Ops url not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to publish app from Azure DevOps to appcenter.ms

I have code building and artifacts are being generated. However, step to upload the app to appcenter always fails with the same error:

```
2019-01-28T14:40:34.0252515Z ##[error]"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST //apps//company/appname//release_uploads</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
http response code: 404
```

I have added a service connection under Azure DevOps:

> **Name:** api
>
> **Server URL:** https://api.appcenter.ms
>
> **API Token:** XXXXX

I'm using App Center Distribute step to publish.

Under build config I got app slug set correctly. What API endpoint I should use?

Comment: Did you follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this endpoint. I've got this issue too and stuck up for days trying to find the right answer but no reference says they change the endpoint.

Server URL: https://api.mobile.azure.com/v0.1

Answer (score 0):

Although the instructions currently suggest otherwise I had success in using the org style APP SLUG setting and it fixed my issue.

{user}/{appname} is the format that worked for me.